# Kill callback rake

Tags: ruby, rake, kill

I have a really long rake task that finish with writting the result in a file. I would like to kill it but get it's current result written in the file.

I know I could make it write to the file at each iteration but that would make it even longer. So is there a way to call a function before the task is killed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the process is killed gracefully (i.e. not via `kill -9`, or any other `SIGKILL`), you can rescue from the signal and "do something" before terminating. (Or even refuse to terminate, if you want!)

The most basic approach would be to define an [`at_exit`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-at_exit) proc:

```
at_exit { write_something_to_file }
```

Or, you could be more granular and define `rescue` blocks within the code:

```
rescue SystemExit, Interrupt
  # ...
```

...Or, you could establish even more control by "killing" the process via custom signals (e.g. `USR1`), instead of sending `SIGINT`: https://ruby-doc.org/core/Signal.html.

There are many variant approaches you could take, so long as it's not a `SIGKILL` being sent, as that's uncatchable by design.